# XCode4 - Dragged a project into another project's workspace and can't remove it

Tags: xcode4

I dragged a static library project into my other project in an attempt to keep my common code in once place, but I now cannot remove that project. It sits above my project in the list on the left and causes a bug in 'add files' where any file you add can only be added to my library project...

I ended up deleting the library project in finder, but that didn't help and now when I try to add files to my project it fails attempting to add them to the nonexistant library project.

Anyway right click - delete isn't highlighted, so is there another way to remove a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

file -> Save As Workspace fixes the problem. If you hit this please write up a bug to Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be possible to open the `ProjectName.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata` in a text editor and remove the project from there.